# Accumulated distance between points

Tags: pyqgis, point, coordinates, distance, expression

I have this piece of code that I can make lines between points and calculate the length of the line, but now I need to calculate the accumulated distance only between the X axis, I managed to use expressions like `p2.x() + p1.x()` to calculate this but when I try to put it in a field it says that it is not possible because the type of the variable is float. How could I do this?

```py
iter1 = layer.getFeatures()
for feature1 in iter1:
    p1 = feature1.geometry().asPoint()
    # loop all points again:
    iter2 = layer.getFeatures()
    for feature2 in iter2:
        # following line creates lines from one feature to previous feature:
        if feature2.id() == feature1.id() + 1:
            # create new line feature:
            p2 = feature2.geometry().asPoint()
            l = QgsGeometry.fromPolylineXY([p1,p2])
            linha = QgsFeature()
            linha.setGeometry(l)
            linha.setAttributes([l.length()])
            pr.addFeature(linha)


vl.updateFields()
```

Comment: Change the field type by refactoring (use [this](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectortable.html#refactor-fields) tool to refactor in QGIS), or convert the python float to integer with the `int` function (`int(p2.x() + p1.x())`) if you don't care about loosing the decimal precision.

Comment: I tried this and got the error: argument 1 has unexpected type 'int'

Comment: So what type of field do you have?

Comment: Double type field